# rails blog add comment redirecting to active admin login page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I am creating a blogging application which uses `active_admin` for admin panel.
When I try to comment on a post it is redirecting me to `active_admin` login page.

Comment Model:-

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true
  attr_accessible :text, :user_id, :post_id

  validate :text, :presence => true
end
```

Active Admin Comment Model:-

```
ActiveAdmin.register Comment, :as => "PostComment" do

end
```

Posts Controller:-

```
def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @showPost = true
    respond_with do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @post }
    end
end
```

Comments Controller:-

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :auth_user

   def create
     @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
     params[:comment][:user_id] = current_user.id
     @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment])
     redirect_to post_path(@post)
   end
end
```

Comment Form:-

```
<%= semantic_form_for ([@post, @post.comments.build]), :html => { :id => "comment-form", :class => "metta-form"} do |f| %>
    <h5 class="pull-left">Comments</h5>
  <div class="clearfix">
  </div>
    <div class="wrap-comment-form">
        <%= f.inputs do %>
            <%= f.input :text, :label => false, :input_html => { :class => "comment-text pull-left" } %>
        <% end %>
        <%= f.actions do %>
            <%= f.action :submit, :label => "Add Comment", :button_html => { :placeholder => "Enter Your Comment Here", :class => "btn btn-primary btn-metta pull-right" } %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

When I click on the add comment button it takes me to active admin login page. Can someone help me out here ??

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  helper ApplicationHelper

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource) 
    '/users/home'
    end
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    '/users/home'
  end
  def auth_user
    redirect_to new_user_path unless user_signed_in?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Look here: `before_filter :auth_user`

So the reason you have been redirected to login page is you have not logged in yet.

Comment: I am logged in. The auth_user action is defined in applications controller. It prevents user from getting to that page. I am using this function in all the views except home page.

Comment: I have added application controller in my question.

Comment: The only logic to redirect to sign in page is that `before_filter`. If you've already signed in, you may want to check if the method `user_singed_in?` works as expected, to really return true for signed in user.

Comment: I have checked, and `user_signed_in?` works. Also the sign in page to which an unauthorized user is being redirected for other views is my own custom sign in page not the `active_admin` sign in page. This is happening only while trying to add new comment.